# Natural Deduction and Sequent Calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, natural-deduction, sequent-calculus

Are there any good natural deduction and sequent calculus solvers online for both predicate and propositional logic? Or perhaps forums that specialise in these proof systems?